# Adjust UITableViewCell height on delete swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` with dynamic height based on textual content.  In `tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` the height gets calculated.  This works well.

When the cell enters editing mode with editingStyle `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` it indents the cell a little and can push the content out some causing the rowHeight to change.  Again this works well as switching the tableview to editing causes the table to relayout and therefor the rowHeight gets recalculated.

When you click the red button or swipe the cell a Delete button appears on right hand side of the cell.  This however does NOT trigger a relayout of the table, only the cell itself.  The problem here is that if the content goes over the bottom edge the cell does not get resized.

Is there a way to trigger a re-layout of the table when the delete button appears?

Answer (score 1):

In general, height of `UITableViewCell` can be only setup via `tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, and the latter method only be called once (per row per section) before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so you have to `[tableview reloadData]` if want to adjust the UITableViewCell height.

Maybe your can do something in these delegate methods

```
// The willBegin/didEnd methods are called whenever the 'editing' property is automatically changed by the table (allowing insert/delete/move). This is done by a swipe activating a single row
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To your question, you could reset the properties of the text control at `- (void)layoutSubviews` in your custom UITableViewCell.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat theWidth = self.frame.size.height; //changed when entering the edit style
    ...
}
```

Hope these will help you.

Comment: [will/didBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath] are only triggered on slide and not if you press the red button.  I did find that willTransitionToState can be used to detect the change.  Unfortunately  [reloadData] causes infinite loops if called inside those methods. I guess I can put it on a timer, but that feels so wrong.